# Проблема с установкой Манжаро Линукс

Tags: linux, установка

Господа Линуксоиды! 
У меня очень глупая проблема, которую я не в состоянии решить.
В окне установки Манжаро во время выбора языка кнопка "далее" не нажимается. 
Прошарил все форумы, ответ не нешёл.
Подскажите в чём проблема.

Comment: на странице выбора языка нет кнопки далее. Она есть на странице выбора клавиатуры. https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5

Comment: @KoVadim таки есть по вашей ссылке. В разделе "Выбор языка установки".

Comment: судя по скриншоту - она рабочая. Может просто мышка не работает в этот момент? я  бы попробывал понажимать <kbd>Tab</kbd> что бы дойти до нужной кнопки и нажать Enter. А другие кнопки нажимаются?